# Как изменить порядок колонок в bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Вот есть структура:

```html
<container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">2</div>
  </div>
</container>
```

При сужении экрана первая колонка остаётся на верху а вторая съезжает в низ. Как сделать чтобы второй блок был на верху а первый в низу при сужении?

Comment: А что за тег такой `<container>` ? И если указано `col-sm-6` то `col-lg-6 col-md-6` это лишнее. А для переупорядочивания колонок в бутстрапе  есть классы [push и pull](https://itchief.ru/lessons/bootstrap-3/85-bootstrap-3-reordering-columns-grid-system)

Comment: Cпасибо. Могли бы и в ответ написать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Поменяйте блоки в верстке местами - чтобы сначала шел блок 2, потом 1.
2. Для sm-экранов - примените классы как в примере ниже
3. Для md и lg-экранов - классы можете не указывать. т.к. расположение блоков у вас на них такое же, как на sm.

Получится так:

```
<container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">1</div>
  </div>
</container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Порядок вывода двух блоков можно менять для разных разрешений. В данном коде при изменении размера до "телефонного", первым будет отображен 2-й блок:

```
<container>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-first order-last>1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-last order-first>2</div>
    </div>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Выше описанные методы, либо устаревшие либо не работают.
Для Bootstrap 4.4.1 можно сделать так, проверено:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <container>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 
                        order-2 
                        order-sm-2 order-lg-1"
                 style="background:red"><h3>MENU</h3></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 
                        order-1 
                        order-sm-1 order-lg-2" 
                 style="background:yellow"><h2>CONTENT</h2></div>
        </div>
    </container>
```

https://codepen.io/a22432/pen/zYvZwOW

Comment: в соседнем же [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/941035/186999) то же самое

Comment: То что написал Vlad Chikov не работает

Comment: ты используешь те же самые классы order-* что и он

Comment: Проверил его пример... и впрямь работает на последней версии, почему то до этого не работало... Возможно я использовал более раннюю версию Bootstrap... Вы Grundy правы.